# Ordering a list based on a property of a child list

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of two 'Vacancies' in the example below and would like to order the list by 'DocumentTitle'. It's sufficient to order the document title in each vacancy then order the list by the first DocumentTitle of each vacancy. I tried many perforations of `VacancyList.OrderBy(x => x.Documents.OrderBy(y => y.DocumentTitle))).ToList()` to no avail

```
    namespace ConsoleApp1
            {
                class Program
                {
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        List<Vacancy> vacancy = new List<Vacancy>
                        {
                            new Vacancy                    
                            {
                                Documents = new List<JobDocumentViewModel>
                                {
                                    new JobDocumentViewModel{DocumentTitle = "H",FileName="Somefile"},                        
                                    new JobDocumentViewModel{DocumentTitle = "A",FileName="Somefile"},
                                    new JobDocumentViewModel{DocumentTitle = "C",FileName="Somefile"}
                                }
                            },
                            new Vacancy
                            {
                                Documents = new List<JobDocumentViewModel>
                                {
                                    new JobDocumentViewModel{DocumentTitle = "Z",FileName="Somefile"},
                                    new JobDocumentViewModel{DocumentTitle = "B",FileName="Somefile"},
                                    new JobDocumentViewModel{DocumentTitle = "X",FileName="Somefile"}
                                }
                            }
                        };
    // What lambda expression would go here to order the vacancies by the document title
//Output - since the document title is "A" in the first vacancy then that would be first and the second vacancy document title of "B" would be next
                    }
                }
                public class Vacancy
                {
                    private List<JobDocumentViewModel> _documents;
                    public List<JobDocumentViewModel> Documents
                    {
                        get
                        {
                            if (_documents == null)
                                _documents = new List<JobDocumentViewModel>();

                            return _documents;
                        }
                        set { _documents = value; }
                    }
                }

                public class JobDocumentViewModel
                {
                    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
                    public string FileName { get; set; }

                    public JobDocumentViewModel() { }
                    public JobDocumentViewModel(
                        string documentTitle,
                        string fileName)
                    {
                        DocumentTitle = documentTitle;
                        FileName = fileName;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: what about the redundant data Like the records with title c in vacany 1

Comment: can you show the output?

Comment: you can't order by a set. You must use an aggregation function. That is order by `Documents.Min(d => d.DocumentTitle)`

Comment: @ThierryV the output would be the same order as the code as the first vacancy document title is "A" and the second vacancy document title is "B"

Comment: @tschmit007 I tried var vacancylist = vacancy.OrderBy(d => d.Documents.Min()); but getting an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this : https://dotnetfiddle.net/SzuuiF

```
vacancy.ForEach(x => x.Documents = x.Documents.OrderBy(y=> y.DocumentTitle).ToList());
var ordered = vacancy.OrderBy(x=> x.Documents.FirstOrDefault()?.DocumentTitle);
```

Comment: And if the list is huge and if you are performance concerned then you can always use the `Parallel.ForEach(vacancy, x => x.Documents = x.Documents.OrderBy(y=> y.DocumentTitle).ToList())`